# Triggering JS from PHP form process

Tags: php, javascript, forms, events, analytics

I have form, let's say it's on index.php. On submit, it goes through process.php, then finishes on thanks.php. I want to trigger an Analytics Event so I can track my form (no I don't want to use a URL Destination). If I put the Event code on thanks.php, I'm concerned that if people refresh the page, it will re-trigger and give me bad results. So, I want it to trigger from process.php somehow. At the end of process.php, I set the header like this:

```
header('Location: /thanks.php');
```

This is the code for triggering the Event:

```
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'ClaimDomain', 'ConfirmationPage']);
```

Is there some way of sending the JavaScript call along with the header, so that it only gets processed as we leave process.php, and not when we refresh thanks.php?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Google Analytics should filter most of that for you

Comment: I need to set up a goal in Analytics so we can track it, so I need something to track. The URL destination method does not work, because the URL has queries on it and it's not matching. So we need to use the Event method.

Comment: You could put a submit handler on the form that fires the Google Analytics event? http://alexking.org/blog/2003/10/01/javascript-onsubmit-handler

Comment: But then it would fire even if the form had errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, PHP is server-side, Javascript is client-side.

From reading about this though, it sounds like it may be a non-issue:

> **Unique events are incremented by unique actions**
>
> Any time a user interacts with an object tagged with a particular
>   action name, the initial interaction is logged as one unique event for
>   that action name. Any additional interaction with the same action
>   trigger for that user's session will not contribute to the unique
>   event calculation for that particular action. This is true even if the
>   user leaves that object and begins to interact with another object
>   tagged via the same action name.

Source: [Event Tracker Guide - Actions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/eventTrackerGuide#Actions).

So GA will know if they happen to land on the page twice and it will not count as 2 unique events.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks for looking into that! I'll test it with it just on the thanks.php page and refresh it a bunch today, will accept this as an answer when I can see the results.

Comment: Hopefully I understand the docs correctly and that is the case.  If you send a `Location` header, the browser will ignore any HTML/JS in the response body, so unfortunately you cannot evaluate any scripts there.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comment above and researched by @drew, it's a non issue.

If you also want to track the goal. Use a "head match" to do so.

http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=72285